# Can unsigned integer incrementation lead to undefined defined behavior?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, undefined-behavior

After reading the [32 bit unsigned multiply on 64 bit causing undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27001604/1806289) question here on StackOverflow, I began to ponder whether typical arithmetic operations on small unsigned types could lead to undefined behavior according to the C99 standard.

For example, take the following code:

```
#include <limits.h>

...

unsigned char x = UCHAR_MAX;
unsigned char y = x + 1;
```

The `x` variable is initialized to the maximum magnitude for the `unsigned char` data type. The next line is the issue: the value `x + 1` is greater than `UCHAR_MAX` and cannot be stored in the `unsigned char` variable `y`.

I believe the following is what actually occurs.

- The variable `x` is first promoted to data type `int` (section **6.3.1.1/2**), then `x + 1` is evaluated as data type `int`.

Suppose there is an implementation where `INT_MAX` and `UCHAR_MAX` are the same -- `x + 1` would result in a signed integer overflow. Does this mean that incrementing the variable `x`, despite being an unsigned integer type, can lead to undefined behavior due to a possible signed integer overflow?

Comment: If `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(int)`, the first scenario applies.

Comment: @chux Why would a promotion not occur if an `int` can represent the value?

Comment: I'll review "6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions"  This seems to first apply "Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type."  That comes before the "Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type ..." rule.

Comment: @chux I think that section of the paragraph applies only after the typical integer promotions occur for each operand: **6.3.1.8/1** "Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands."

Comment: I sit corrected. If `INT_MAX >= UCHAR_MAX`, `unsigned char x` is converted per "Usual arithmetic conversions" to `int`.

Comment: Suppose this is why code should use `unsigned char y = x + 1u`.

Comment: `INT_MAX == UCHAR_MAX` implies at least 7 padding bits for `int`, that doesn't sound likely to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By my reading of the standard, an implementation which used a 15-bit `char` could legally store `int` as a 15-bit magnitude and use a second 15-bit word to store the sign along with 14 bits of padding; in that case, an `unsigned char` would hold values 0 to 32,767 and an `int` would hold values from -32,767 to +32,767.  Adding 1 to `(unsigned char)32767` would indeed be undefined behavior.  A similar situation could arise with any larger `char` size if 32,767 was replaced with `UCHAR_MAX`.

Such a situation is unlikely, however, compared with the real-world problems associated with unsigned integer multiplication alluded to in the other post.