# Integer literal for fixed width integer types

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, literals

Is there some c++ proposal for Integer literal for fixed width integer types like this?

```
// i's type is unsigned int
auto i = 10u;
// j's type is uint32_t
auto j = 10u32;
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406333/fixed-width-integer-literals-in-c

Comment: The old C99 way is to use macros in [stdint.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) - for example: `INT8_C(127)`, `UINT16_C(65535)`, `UINT32_C(10)`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes: [P1280R0 Integer Width Literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1280r0.html) (published 2018-10-05).

It proposes the following literals:

```cpp
namespace std::inline literals::inline integer_literals {
  constexpr uint64_t operator ""u64 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr uint32_t operator ""u32 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr uint16_t operator ""u16 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr uint8_t operator ""u8 (unsigned long long arg);

  constexpr int64_t operator ""i64 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr int32_t operator ""i32 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr int16_t operator ""i16 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr int8_t operator ""i8 (unsigned long long arg);
}
```

And its update [P1280R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1280r1.html) that "Modifies return types to actually be `[u]int_leastXX_t` and friends. This is to make sure that we are actually replacing the `[U]INTxx_C` macros, as these return a `[u]int_leastXX_t`":

```cpp
namespace std::inline literals::inline integer_literals {
  constexpr uint_least64_t operator ""u64 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr uint_least32_t operator ""u32 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr uint_least16_t operator ""u16 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr uint_least8_t operator ""u8 (unsigned long long arg);

  constexpr int_least64_t operator ""i64 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr int_least32_t operator ""i32 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr int_least16_t operator ""i16 (unsigned long long arg);
  constexpr int_least8_t operator ""i8 (unsigned long long arg);
}
```

There is a 2019-06-12 update [P1280R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1280r2.html) that makes the literals `consteval` instead of `constexpr`.

Comment: fwiw, I think that update made it worse. If I write `auto x = 5u32`; I want a 32bit integer and not "maybe something else that will fail on other platform"

Comment: @RiaD -- it's `uint32_t` that will fail on some other platform. `uint_least32_t` is **always** available; `uint32_t` won't exist on (admittedly unusual) platforms that don't have a native 32-bit integer type.  That's an inherent ambiguity with fixed-size integer types: you might want an exact size, or you might want something large enough to hold some number of bits.

Comment: @PeteBecker 1) "platform doesn't support uint32, so I won't compile 5u32" is straightforward compiler error
2) "in some random place where uint_least32_t is used, some overloading is now ambiguous" (suppose that uint32_least_t=unsigned long long and the same example will be broken as in P1280) is less straight forward.

I of course agree that you might want uint32_least_t, but why not use 5u_least32 ?

Comment: @RiaD -- re: `5u_least32` -- isn't that self-answering? <g> Yes, I overlooked the point you make about ambiguous overloads.

Comment: The fixed-width types come with a bunch of ambiguity anyway thanks to the interaction with the integer promotions. Does adding two `int32_t`s result in an `int32_t`? Not if you're on a system where `int` is 64-bit!

Comment: And does multiplying two large `uint16_t`s and storing the result in a `uint16_t` variable result in wraparound or undefined behavior? Integer math in C/C++ is a horrible mess.

Comment: Multiplying two `uint16_t` of `0xFFFF` can indeed cause signed overflow (undefined behavior!) on a platform where int is 32 bits. See threads like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001604/32-bit-unsigned-multiply-on-64-bit-causing-undefined-behavior ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964651/is-masking-before-unsigned-left-shift-in-c-c-too-paranoid ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795651/whats-the-best-c-way-to-multiply-unsigned-integers-modularly-safely